# Updating a MVVM View when model property is set to new instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel and a View in a WPF application. On the screen there are a selection of inputs (date picker, text box and combobox).

The inputs are bound to the NewItem property of the ViewModel, the DataGrid is bound to the WorkLog collection property.

When the user clicks on the Add button I want the NewItem to be added to the WorkLog collection, and the NewItem property reset in order to allow the user to add more items. The problem is that when I add the item, if I reinstantiate NewItem then the controls are still populated but in the background the VM values are all defaults (or nulls) so it doesn't work.

How can I reset the NewItem property and update the UI to reflect this? I tried INotifyPropertyChanged to no avail (as I am setting to new instance rather than changing values).

I have trimmed the code for brevity

Model

```
public class WorkLogItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WorkLogItem()
    {
        this.Datestamp = DateTime.Today;
        this.Staff = new Lookup();
        this.WorkItem = new Lookup();
    }

    #region ID

    private Int32 _ID;

    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return this._ID; }
        set
        {
            this._ID = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Datestamp

    private DateTime? _Datestamp;

    public DateTime? Datestamp
    {
        get { return this._Datestamp; }
        set
        {
            this._Datestamp = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Datestamp");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Staff

    private Model.Lookup _Staff;

    public Model.Lookup Staff
    {
        get { return this._Staff; }
        set
        {
            this._Staff = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Staff");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region WorkItem

    private Model.Lookup _WorkItem;

    public Model.Lookup WorkItem
    {
        get { return this._WorkItem; }
        set
        {
            this._WorkItem = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("WorkItem");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Hours

    private Decimal _Hours;

    public Decimal Hours
    {
        get { return this._Hours; }
        set
        {
            this._Hours = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Hours");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(String name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

View Model

```
public Model.WorkLogItem NewItem { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Model.WorkLogItem> WorkLog { get; set; }
```

View

```
<Label Content="Date " />
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.NewItem.Datestamp, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />

<Label Content="Work Item " />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.WorkItems}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.WorkLogItem.Type, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

<Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Hours " />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.NewItem.Hours, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
```

C#

In Window_Loaded:

```
this.DataContext = this.VM;
```

In Add_Click

```
this.VM.WorkLog.Add(this.VM.NewItem);

this.VM.NewItem = new Model.WorkLogItem();
```

Comment: I don't see `NotifyPropertyChange` nor `ObservableCollection<T>` anywhere in your code. You need these for 2-way binding.

Comment: Thanks. I had implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and changed all Lists to ObservableCollections but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` must also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model.WorkLogItem _newItem;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        NewItem = new Model.WorkLogItem();
        WorkLog  = new ObservableCollection<Model.WorkLogItem>();
    }

    public Model.WorkLogItem NewItem
    { 
        get { return _newItem; }
        set
        {
            _newItem = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("NewItem");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model.WorkLogItem> WorkLog { get; set; }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here...
}
```

When binding to your `ComboBox`, be sure to use `Mode=TwoWay`:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem="{Binding ... Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That is what I was missing and it is now working (almost). I will mark this as the answer, do you have any idea why my ComboBox would not reset the selected item? I have used IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"

Comment: Check that the Binding has `Mode=TwoWay` (see the bottom of the answer).

Comment: I have that, and also have NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True

Comment: Can you describe the meaning of "reset the selected item"? Which direction is the data going? Is the ComboBox not getting reset to empty?

Comment: The ComboBox is still showing whatever item I had selected, although if I click Add again the selected item in the background is null

Comment: @RobKing: I've got the same problem currently, did you solve this behavior?

Comment: @Herm Be sure to check your output window when debugging for any Binding errors. The binding for the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` in the XAML above is not correct.

Comment: my binding was correct, but this article described the same phenomen, so I used a behavior to update the binding: http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2011/04/28/the-case-of-the-confused-combobox-a-wpfmvvm-bedtime-story/ now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do this is to set up an empty constructor in my data object that sets all of its properties to their default values. Then when I want to 'reset' a view to all empty fields, I just set my data bound property to a new item:

```
NewItem = new YourDataType();
```

This updates all of the data bound control properties as you would expect. Please note that my data type classes all implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and that this method of clearing the UI controls will only work if they do implement it.

Comment: I had tried instantiating it to a new instance but I hadn't explicitly set the values in the constructor. I have now tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. My values are all reset so my object is correct, but the UI doesn't change - I think it is because it is a new instance rather than a value change so the UI isn't notified.

Comment: My UI gets cleared when I set the property to a new instance... the UI doesn't know or care if the object was changed... it's just binding to the property values which are made empty in the new instance.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing differently. I have added NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True to the XAML binding, I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on every property, and my C# is simply this.VM.WorkLog.Add(this.VM.WorkLogItem);

this.VM.WorkLogItem = new Model.WorkLogItem();

Comment: If you call `this.VM.WorkLog.Add(new Model.WorkLogItem());`, do the UI properties get set to the values from the new instance?

Comment: No, same UI effect but my collection has an empty item added. I have updated the question with my updated code

Comment: Before these comments get too big, I would suggest that you leave your current project and start a new WPF application to test your binding. If you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then it should all work... maybe if you removed the complexity of your current project while you worked through this issue, it would help? This *should* be simple to achieve, so if it is not working, it *could* be because of other code in your current application. Good luck.